# Table Creation in Xcode for Iphone

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad

When I write a simple code to create a table, I got `_CGRect referenced From` error. I don't know how to solve this error. I even added the `CoreGraphics` framework into my project

```
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier  = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{ 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CGRectMake(0,0,widthOfCell,heightOfCell)
```

in your

```
cell initWithFrame
```

method, i think tht should do it for you.

Comment: Thank u dude.But I don 've any methode like that

Comment: of course you do. check your own code.  cell = uitableviecell initwithframe